# jQuery Autocomplete JSON with JSON.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, json.net

I must be missing something here, but I'm trying to use jQuery UI's autocomplete with an ASP.NET page method. I'm using JSON.NET to serialize the response of the method, which definitely works, and returns this:

```
[{"ADMIN_ID":1,"ADMIN_NAME":"SMITH"}]
```

...and here is my jquery code:

```
$("#txtName").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyPage.aspx/GetPerson",
            data: "{ 'q': '" + request.term + "', 'limit': '10' }",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                var result = $.parseJSON(data.d)
                response($.map(result, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.ADMIN_NAME,
                        value: item.ADMIN_ID
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1
});
```

Problem is, the autocomplete never shows any items. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm an idiot, I didn't parse the JSON when it came back from my page method. Added this code above: var result = $.parseJSON(data.d)

Answer (score 0):

Try this first, I think your response(...) code is the culprit:

```
$('#txtName').result(function(event, data, formatted) {
   $("#result").html( !data ? "No match!" : "Selected: " + formatted);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that #result was just used to display the JSON string from the method. I took that out of the original code.